# Keeps looping. Tried other threads, didn't work

Tags: python, loops, shapes

I've been doing  programming for about 4 weeks now. Loving it so far. But I am stuck on this piece of code that I'm writing. It's about area of shapes. I tried to look on here and saw a couple of threads but it didn't help.
It keeps looping when I don't want it to.

Updated:

```
#Area of shapes
shape=[]
choice= None
while choice !="0":
    print (
        """
Choices:
0. Exit
1.Square
2.Rectangle
3.Triangle
4.Trapezium
    """
        )

    choice = input ("Choice\n")
    print()

#Exit
if choice != "0":
    print ("Incorrect, please try again")

#Square
    elif choice in ["1", "Square"]:
        square1=int(input("Please input the side of the square\n"))
        print ("The area of the square is", square1*4,)


#Rectangle
    elif choice in ["1", "Rectangle"]:
        rectangle1 = int(input ("Please input the side of the reactanglezn") )
        rectangle2 = int(input ("Please input the other side of the reactangle\n") )
        arearect== rectangle1*rectangle2
        print ("The area of the rectangle is of", arearect)

#Triangle
    elif choice in ["1", "Triangle"]:
        triangle1 = int(input ("Please input the base of the triangle") )
        triangle2 = int(input ("Please input the height of the triangle") )
        areatri =0.5*triangle1*triangle2
        print ("The area of the triangle is", areatri)

#Trapezium
    elif choice in ["1", "Trapezium"]:
        trapezium1 = int(input ("Please input the side A of the trapezium") )
        trapezium2= int(input ("Please input the side B of the trapezium") )
        trapezium3= int(input ("Please input the height of the trapezium") )
        areatrap= trapezium1*trapezium2/2*trapezium3
        print ("The area of the trapezium is", areatrap)

    else:
        print ("Invalid Choice")
```

Comment: The indentation is wrong. You must indent at least one more line below the `while`: the `choice = input()` one.

Comment: Can you clarify if the indentation shown in the question matches your actual code. Also, can you show exactly what's happening? Is the input and area calculation repeating forever, or just the initial prompt?

Comment: Repeating forever @Blckknght

Comment: Please be more specific. *What part* is repeating forever?

Comment: @Blckknght The choice option                                                                              Choices:
0. Exit
1.Square
2.Rectangle
3.Triangle
4.Trapezium
    """
        )

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your If statements to look like this

```
If choice == "1" or choice == "Square"
```

With the way you have it now, you're not checking to see if choice equals the string "Square", you're checking to see if the string "Square" exists.

edit:  I just realized that doesn't actually answer your looping question, but you will run into that issue once the loop is resolved.
To resolve it, you'll need to cast your input to a string, since you're comparing it to a string value.  To do so, you can do the following:

```
choice  str(input("Choice\n"))
```

in place of what you have now.

Comment: Putting a `str` call around `input` won't do anything useful in Python 3, which I'm guessing the questioner is using, given the `print()` function calls.

Comment: Ah, won't it?  I tested it using 2.6.1 which is what trypython.org uses (my work computer doesn't have it installed.) The print() function calls also exist in that version so I wasn't sure.

Comment: `print` is a statement in Python 2, rather than a function (unless you request the newer behavior by putting `from __future__ import print_function` above the rest of your code). You can still parenthesize the arguments, but if there is more than one, you'll print a tuple rather than space-separated values (parenthesizing one argument doesn't do anything).

Comment: Ah yes, so it does.  It's been a long time since I extensively Pythoned and it's been almost always 2.7 or mostly 3.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what is causing the infinite loop.  I've tested it at wandbox using their Python 3.5 interpreter and it worked just fine for me, using the indentation lifted directly from his question.   I actually don't see the indentation issue others mentioned.  The prompt print call and the input call are both indented in one level. The presence, absence, or positioning of the blank print call doesn't do anything when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an indent on line 14 (the one that changes the value of choice) to correct your syntax.

Pay attention to indents, as they can easily break your code in functions, if/elses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent most of your code so that it's within your top-level loop. Currently, starting with the `print()` call immediately after you get the `choice`, you're outside the loop, which means that entering anything other than `0` doesn't do anything. Entering `0` will exit the loop, but won't do any area computations.

The structure of your code should be something like:

```
while choice != "0":
    # print choices
    choice = input ("Choice\n")
    print()

    if choice == "0":
        # print exit message
    elif choice in ["1", "Square"]:
        # compute area of square
    elif choice in ["1", "Rectangle"]:
        # compute area of rectangle
    # other options
    else:
        # invalid choice
```

I've also fixed the issue with your `elif` conditions, where you were improperly checking for mutliple values. This is an alternative to `if choice == "1" or choice == "Square"`, which also works just fine.

Comment: I updated the code to your standard @Blckknght , it says that the elif's are invalid syntaxes.

Comment: Your first `if` statement and the `print` underneath it are not indented like they should be. Indentation is significant in Python, you must get it right!